# Identifying Total Number of Rows, then Copying and Pasting a values to the number of rows

Tags: excel, vba, rowcount, pasting

I'm looking to create a macro that will essentially identify the total number of rows on a sheet. Then take the values in a range on another sheet, copy that range, and paste it until it reaches the total number of rows that was identified on the first sheet. I am NOT looking to take a set of values and copy it to the last row of another sheet.

This is what I have so far. I'm having trouble trying to find the next step to take to accomplish my goal. I think I'm close, but my knowledge of variables is very limited.

```
Public Sub Delegation()

    Dim lastrow As String
    lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Worksheets("delegating").Range("A1:A13").Copy _

End Sub
```

Comment: Let's start that `Dim lastrow As Long` as you are trying to get the number of rows (not a `String`). Then to copy, you need to use it, like `Worksheets("delegating").Range("A1:A" & lastrow).Copy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
Public Sub Delegation()

    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    With Worksheets("delegating")
        .Range("A1:A13").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("A1:A" & lastrow), _
                                  Type:=xlFillCopy
    End With 
End Sub
```